# Active Directory Linqpad vs Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, active-directory, linqpad

I have a need to authenticate a User against Active Directory. The same code is running in Visual Studio as well as LinqPad. LinqPad works fine However within Visual Studio, it errors with a very helpful unknown error, the stack  trace is as follows:

```
System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapException: A local error occurred.    
     at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.BindHelper(NetworkCredential newCredential, Boolean needSetCredential)    
     at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.CredentialValidator.lockedLdapBind(LdapConnection current, NetworkCredential creds, ContextOptions contextOptions)    
     at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.CredentialValidator.BindLdap(NetworkCredential creds, ContextOptions contextOptions)    
     at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.CredentialValidator.Validate(String userName, String password)    
     at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials(String userName, String password)
```

The code that is in both but only runs in LinqPad is:

```
using (System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext pc = new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext(System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType.Domain))
{
   return pc.ValidateCredentials("SomeName", SomePassword");
}
```

I have also ran the exe outside of VS with / without Admin and also using the runas from a cmd line. 
If anyone has any knowledge of why these are behaving different then it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to this I tried this on both local , Remote Server and both work

> If the user is null that means that they are not found in AD

```
string fullName = null;
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context,"your domain username goes here"))
    {
        if (user != null)
        {
            fullName = user.DisplayName;
        }
    }
}
```